# Why crash happens during getting property 'description'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Help me please.

Why it happens and how it can be fixed?

It's my code:

```
NSString* description = view.description;
```

It works if view is kind of class `UIButton` or `UILabel` or other.

But it crashes if view is kind of class `UIWebBrowserView` and I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Why it happens?
'description' is property of class `NSObject`, all classes extend of `NSObject`, than why I have `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try get this property from object, which is kind of class `UIWebBrowserView`?

More code:

Creating `UIWebView` in `ViewController`:

```
UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120)];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Than using swizzle mechanism I get `UIView` on which click is happens and try get `description` from this view.

```
NSSet * allTouches = [anUIEvent allTouches];
UITouch * touch = [allTouches anyObject];
UIView * view = touch.view;
NSString* description = view.description;
```

Error in console:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x17d45fc0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Comment: Without seeing the code in context, there's no telling.  A wild guess is that you don't have a valid reference anymore (i.e. the object you were pointing to was deallocated).

Comment: It can be, because sometimes (very rarely) this code works without errors and I get this property from UIWebBrowserView.

Comment: If you're using ARC, check for properties declared with `(assign)`.  If you're not using ARC, start using ARC.

Comment: Better to show your coding

Comment: I use ARC. I can get property 'hash' from object, which is kind of class UIWebBrowserView

Comment: Katya show your coding please

Comment: What do you mean? My code or encoding?

Comment: @user3182143 Coding added

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: "Than using swizzle mechanism" - that is the answer. If you try to handle touches in `UIWebView`, you should handle `shouldStartLoad...` delegates method.

Comment: I use swizzle mechanism for caughting of clicks on all views (not only for webview). But error I have only with webview.

Comment: @Droppy, attached error from console.

Comment: it works if I call it on main tread `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });`

Comment: thanks everyone :)